# "Informing" the compiler what kind of ArrayList I am using

Tags: java, arraylist

The following code is a method in a constructor. .For some reason Eclipse declares an error in the fourth line of the code "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable". the arraylist I am going to put as an argument in the method id made of booleans

```
boolean Referring(ArrayList results){
        int so = 0;
        int ca = 0;


            if (results.get(0) **** the error is here **** = false){
                return false;
        }
        return true;}
```

I think the error occurs because the compiler "doesn't know" what kind of arguments are in the ArrayList. Can I "inform him" in some way?

Comment: try `results.get(0) == false`

Comment: Are you trying to do a comparison? Because `=` isn't a comparison operator, `==` is.

Comment: Your error is because you're assigning `false` to a function call.

Comment: Easier: `if (!(Boolean)results.get(0)) { /* */ }`

Comment: I have a slap-o-matic haptic peripheral on my computer, so that when I do this, the compiler does not give an error message, it just slaps me in the face.

Comment: I changed it to two equal signs. It's a stupid error that has no connection to the problem (besides being a big problem by itself:))

Comment: To the editors: Don't fix up the question and fix the actual PROBLEM. Fixing formatting is one thing, fundamentally "breaking" the question by fixing the problem is entirely another thing. Changing `=` to `==` is the ANSWER, so making that change the question negates the purpose of the question and just leaves everyone else wondering what the problem was.

Comment: It's not the problem. The main problem was adding <Boolean>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the error occurs because the compiler "doesn't know" what kind
>   of arguments are in the ArrayList. Can I "inform him" in some way?

Use generics:

```
ArrayList<Boolean> results;
```

More info on generics here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Your other problem stems from using a single = to compare a value. You should either use == or the .equals function depending on what you want to do. But since you're (presumably) working with booleans, you can just refer to them directly:

```
if (!results.get(0)){
```

Comment: I had a look at the documentation before but accidently put <boolean> instead of <Boolean>. Thank you.

Comment: @Atlantis No problem. Capital-B Boolean is known as a *wrapper class* for the primitive lower-case-b boolean. You use wrapper classes for things that require an Object, since primitives aren't Objects. ArrayLists can only contain Objects, so that's why you need to use Boolean instead of boolean. Note that when you do add a primitive boolean to the ArrayList, Java is automatically converting it to a wrapper Boolean through a process called *autoboxing*.

Answer (score 3):

Two errors there.

You should declare the `ArrayList` as `ArrayList<Boolean>`, and use the double equals operator to perform comparison.

```
boolean Referring(ArrayList<Boolean> results){
    int so = 0;
    int ca = 0;
    if (results.get(0) == false){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, with boolean, no comparison is needed. You can just use

```
if (!results.get(0))
```

Comment: Maybe the rest of the elements are not `Boolean`, which shows a bad design from OP.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza By declaring the `ArrayList` the way I'm showing, the `ArrayList` **must** be a boolean `ArrayList`, otherwise the compiler will throw an error

Comment: And I'm saying that probably this is an `ArrayList<Object>` so you should not assume it is `ArrayList<Boolean>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That makes no sense. If the OP wants to do `boolean` comparison, all the object must be `boolean`, so yes, I can assume it. Using an `ArrayList<Object>` makes no sense to me.

Comment: It makes complete sense if you just want to compare the first element and use the others for other kind of operations. Think about it: you may read data from a file and instead of using a class, you just save everything in an array (or `ArrayList results` for ease of use), then load the data read from a `Scanner` into this `results` and send it into another method for analysis, but knowing that only the first element will store a flag for `true/false` whatever purpose it has.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, but as you said this is clearly poor design. That's why I'm not suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` as a comparison operator, not `=`.

Anyway you can put the type of an `ArrayList` between angular brackets: `ArrayList<ObjectType>`.